# How inserting cells in a row or a column different from inserting row(s) or column(s) between rows and columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells

How is this [Inserting cells in a column](https://imgur.com/3X8iC7I)  different from [Inserting a column between two columns](https://imgur.com/0Te6Gwo)

P.S.: It's a curious question, and didn't find anything on the internet; hence, I don't add any additional material.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert cells into a row or column, only those rows and/or columns are being affected in terms of cells being displaced and consequently moved in the direction of your choosing (think Archimedes Principle but in two dimensions, *x* and *y* axes).  However, when you insert an entire row or column, the insertion and displacement is applied across the entirety of the sheet, and the directionality is predetermined (hence no displacement prompt appears).